# Issues with DIV height not resizing

Tags: html, css

I'm having an issue with a few divs within divs.

Ultimately I'd like the user to enter an address into an input box, click a search button, which then triggers an AJAX request (not included). Once the AJAX request has been completed, I want the `resultsDiv` to show (via a `fadeIn` call). There are two divs which act as container divs, with the classes `inner` and `outer` (this provides some padding on the inside of the container).

```css
.outer, .inner {
    display: block;
}

.inner {
    padding: 20px;
    clear: both;
}

.outer {
    width: 65%;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    border-radius: 10px;
    padding: 0px;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 10px 26px 1px rgba(125,125,125,0.67);
    -moz-box-shadow: 0px 10px 26px 1px rgba(125,125,125,0.67);
    box-shadow: 0px 10px 26px 1px rgba(125,125,125,0.67);
}

#subResultsDiv {
    border-radius: 10px;
    border: 1px solid #C3DBE9;
}
```

As you can see [on this jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/h4makhjL/), when the resultsDiv is shown the bottom of the div hangs over the outer div:

[image]

Is there any way to ensure that when the `fadeIn` function is called and the `resultsDiv` is shown, that both the outer and inner div expand with it to stop the "overhang"?

Apologies if the above isn't clear - and thanks in advance for any help

If you have any really good resources about how divs work (e.g. floating, block vs inline vs everything else) - please let me know. I really struggle with this area of CSS.

Comment: Why do you set `height: 260px;` in the DIV's style attribute?

Comment: Ahhh jeez I feel a bit silly, I tried everything previously and hadn't realised that was the culprit. I've removed the height from the style attribute and it works a treat. Thank you for your help, much appreciated